# How to build a random railway based on given number of elements?

Tags: algorithm

I have a number of Lego railway elements - curved rails ([image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KNRMA.jpg)), straight rails ([image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MKWzy.jpg)), sets of points ([image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/36DPy.jpg)) and a crossing element ([bridge](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JgjLf.jpg)).

I would like to write a program, which will generate a random railway based on number of elements available (probably, with maximum number of elements used). But I never worked with such tasks before. How an algorithm of railway generation should look like? What to start with?

Comment: which constraints do you enforce? Closed tracks? No loose ends? No crossings (apart from using crossing elements or bridges)?

Comment: @Tedil, thanks for the valid questions raised. Yes, the track should be closed, with no loose ends and no crossings.

Answer (score 2):

I implemented a quite similar task with Lego railway elements a few years ago.

First of all, generating a random railway implies that you need to have/need to find valid railways. And finding valid railways (where 'valid' means a closed loop, no overlaps of rail segments etc.) requires a search algorithm; in this case, a backtracking algorithm which traverses the search tree could achieve this.

- Starting situation: As already mentioned, the algorithm should start from a certain position in the 2-dimensional plane and a defined direction (angle), with 0 elements at the beginning.
- A step forward in the backtracking algorithm: ... consists of adding a railway element (e. g. a curve rail element using as a left curve element); when adding a new element, you have to update where the head of your track is and which direction the head is now heading to; and you have to check whether the new element does not overlap with the already existing rail track.
- Solution found: Based on this geometric position, you need to check whether your railway is finished (means: the head of your track connects smoothly to the starting point of your rail track).
- Pruning: You have to implement some heuristics in order to reduce the billion numbers of possible tracks, e. g.: don't continue if the remaining pieces would not be sufficient to come back to the starting point in terms of (a) missing distance and (b) angle difference.

2 more remarks:

- From the result (a list of possible railtracks), all "isomorphisms" should be skipped, e. g. a rail track of 12x right curve (= a perfect circle) is basically the same as a solution consisting of 12x left curve.
- Some trigonometry is required (e. g. for checking whether I have arrived at my starting point); in order to do this without any floating-point imprecision (and also to speed up the execution), the (trigonometrical) problem can be transformed in a way that it operates with integer coefficients only.

Btw. the program has found solutions that I would never have thought of...

Update 30.10.2022: As desired, here is the code, written (as already said) in VBA.

```vb
'---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
'
' Lego Eisenbahn - Finding all possible closed railway tracks given a number of Lego railway elements
'
' Notes:
' - Written in VBA (Visual Basic for Applications); I used to run it as a macro in an Excel file, but should not
'   be a big problem to port it to other environments.
' - Output will be printed into the first excel worksheet (plus some debug messages into a VBA window)
' - Original version was in German; I changed comments into English but did not change German-like variable names
' - Author: Michael T., 2011-2022
'
' About the algorithm:
' - Input: number of railway elements to be used: variable name 'maxtiefe', see below.
' - Currently it supports:
'    - straight elements (in output shown as "-")
'    - left curve elements ("L")
'    - right curce elements ("R")
' - Output: a list of possible solutions (i. e. list of closed railway tracks)
' - Possible extensions:
'    ° other railway elements (like crossings). Can be done in principle but requires some brain work...
'    ° port to another language in order to increase processing speed: currently you have to be patient if you
'      wanna use more than 22 elements...
'    ° of course, more algorithmic optimization (adding more/better heuristics) is possible.
'
'---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Option Explicit ' each variable needs to be declared

'------- Definitions ---------------------

Type kopf_type
  ' The position of the head of the railway
  mx As Integer    ' For more efficient calculation, the x and y positions are decomposed as follows:
  nx As Integer    '     x = mx * squareroot(3)/4 + nx * 1/4
  my As Integer    '     y = my * squareroot(3)/4 + ny * 1/4
  ny As Integer
  
  ' The direction of the head of the railway
  alpha As Integer ' the direction in degrees (0, 30, ..., 330)
  m As Integer     ' for more efficient calculation, the coefficients m, n, p, q are derived from alpha
  n As Integer     ' and will be used for further calculations. The coefficients fulfil the following equations:
  p As Integer     '     cos(alpha) = m * squareroot(3)/2 + n * 1/2
  q As Integer     '     sin(alpha) = p * squareroot(3)/2 + q * 1/2.
End Type

Const sqrt3 As Double = 3 ^ (1 / 2)
Const mm As Double = sqrt3 / 4
Const nn As Double = 1 / 4
Const h2 As Double = 2 - sqrt3 ' Length of a curved element, (german: Sehne, engl.: chord), squared
Const eps As Double = 0.001 ' The tolerance (because of calculation inaccuracy) which I still concede with the heuristics
Const max_num_solutions As Long = 1000000 ' max. number of solutions

'------- Global declarations --------------------

Dim Loesung(1 To max_num_solutions) As String ' the solutions found by the search algorithm will be stored here
Dim istisomorphievon(1 To max_num_solutions) As Long ' needed for finding isormorphies

Dim anzpruefungen As Long
Dim anzloesungen As Long
Dim anzloesungenohneisomorphie As Long

Dim maxtiefe As Integer
 
Sub eisenbahn()
  ' Main procedure

  Dim done As Boolean
  Dim notfound As Boolean
  Dim tStart As Single, tEnde As Single, tGesamtdauer As Single
  Dim k0 As kopf_type
  Dim i As Long, j As Long, k As Long
  Dim ws As Worksheet
  Dim outputzeile As Integer
  
  Set ws = Worksheets(1)
  ws.Columns("A:Z").Value = ""
  outputzeile = 1
  
  Debug.Print
  Debug.Print "--------------------- Eisenbahn -------------------------------------------------------"

  ' Initialization: Position x=y=0, Direction 0 degrees
  k0.mx = 0
  k0.nx = 0
  k0.my = 0
  k0.ny = 0
  k0.alpha = 0
  Call adjust_mnpq(k0)
  
  ' 1) Find solutions by recursive descend / backtracking
  maxtiefe = 19
  anzpruefungen = 0
  anzloesungen = 0
  done = False
  notfound = False
  tStart = Timer
  Call try(k0, 0, "")
  
  Debug.Print "tiefe="; maxtiefe; "done="; done; " notfound="; notfound; " anzpruefungen="; anzpruefungen; " anzloesungen="; anzloesungen
  
  ' 2) Eliminate isomorphies from the result set
  ' 2a) initialize
  For i = 1 To anzloesungen
    istisomorphievon(i) = -1
  Next i
  
  ' 2b) eliminate
  For i = 1 To anzloesungen
    If istisomorphievon(i) = -1 Then
      ' i denotes in fact an equivalence class
      For j = i + 1 To anzloesungen
        If istisomorphievon(j) = -1 Then
          If istIsomorph(Loesung(i), Loesung(j)) Then
            ' j is an isomorphy of i: mark it and do not use j further
            istisomorphievon(j) = i
          End If
        End If
      Next j
    End If
  Next i
  
  ' 2c) Count num of equivalence classes
  anzloesungenohneisomorphie = 0
  For i = 1 To anzloesungen
    If istisomorphievon(i) = -1 Then
      anzloesungenohneisomorphie = anzloesungenohneisomorphie + 1
    End If
  Next i
  
  ' 2d) print out results
  Debug.Print "Anz. Lsg ohne Isomorphie: "; anzloesungenohneisomorphie
  ws.Cells(outputzeile, 1) = "Nr."
  ws.Cells(outputzeile, 2) = "Solution"
  ws.Cells(outputzeile, 3) = "#L"
  ws.Cells(outputzeile, 4) = "#R"
  ws.Cells(outputzeile, 5) = "#-"
  outputzeile = outputzeile + 1
  k = 1
  For i = 1 To anzloesungen
    If istisomorphievon(i) = -1 Then
      ' Count number of L, R, and -
      Dim le As Integer, nL As Integer, nR As Integer
      le = Len(Loesung(i))
      nL = 0
      nR = 0
      For j = 1 To Len(Loesung(i))
        If Mid(Loesung(i), j, 1) = "L" Then
          nL = nL + 1
        ElseIf Mid(Loesung(i), j, 1) = "R" Then
          nR = nR + 1
        End If
      Next j
      ws.Cells(outputzeile, 1) = k
      ws.Cells(outputzeile, 2) = Loesung(i)
      ws.Cells(outputzeile, 3) = nL
      ws.Cells(outputzeile, 4) = nR
      ws.Cells(outputzeile, 5) = le - (nL + nR)
      k = k + 1
      outputzeile = outputzeile + 1
    End If
  Next i

  tEnde = Timer
  tGesamtdauer = tEnde - tStart    ' Duration in seconds
  Debug.Print "dauer/s="; tGesamtdauer

ende:
Debug.Print "^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ END ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^"
End Sub

Sub try(k As kopf_type, tiefe As Integer, weg As String)
  ' Find solutions by recursive descend
  ' k - the current head of the railway, containing position and direction
  ' tiefe (depth) - the current search depth i. e. the current number of elements I have used
  ' weg (track) - the string of elements (L/R/-) currently used
  
  Dim kk As kopf_type
  
  ' check whether we have reached the target
  If tiefe = maxtiefe Then
    anzpruefungen = anzpruefungen + 1
    If k.mx = 0 Then
      If k.nx = 0 Then
        If k.my = 0 Then
          If k.ny = 0 Then
            If k.alpha = 0 Then
              ' we have found a solution
              If anzloesungen = max_num_solutions Then
                ' solution table full
                Debug.Print "Warning: Cannot save new solution since solution table is full."
                GoTo try_ende
              End If
              ' save solution
              anzloesungen = anzloesungen + 1
              Loesung(anzloesungen) = weg
            End If
          End If
        End If
      End If
    End If
    
  Else
    ' maximum depth not yet reached: Search further
      
    ' Heuristics A: Check whether we can reach the target (from a distance point of view) at all with the remaining elements we have
    ' Calculate squared distance to the target (which is (0, 0))
    Dim dist2 As Double, r2 As Double
    dist2 = (k.mx * mm + k.nx * nn) ^ 2 + (k.my * mm + k.ny * nn) ^ 2
    ' Calculate squared remaining distance we could reach with our elements (note that the max. distance can be reached with curved rails)
    r2 = h2 * ((maxtiefe - tiefe) ^ 2)
    If dist2 > r2 + eps Then
      ' Target not reachable anymore: go back
      GoTo try_ende
    End If
    
    ' Heuristics B: Check whether the angle difference to the target can be compensated/reached at all
    If k.alpha = 0 Then
      ' No angle difference to compensate: try further
      GoTo try_weiter
    End If
    Dim beta As Integer ' the angle difference still to be compensated
    Dim ausgleichbarewinkeldifferenz As Integer ' the maximum angle difference we still can compensate
    ausgleichbarewinkeldifferenz = (maxtiefe - tiefe) * 30 ' 30 degrees per remaining element
    If k.alpha <= 180 Then
      beta = k.alpha
    Else ' alpha >180
      beta = 360 - k.alpha
    End If
    If beta > ausgleichbarewinkeldifferenz Then
      ' Target not reachable anymore: go back
      GoTo try_ende
    End If

try_weiter:
    ' Try further
    
    ' 1st possibility: left-curved rail element
    kk = k
    Call ergaenze_bauteil(kk, "bogen links")
    Call try(kk, tiefe + 1, weg + "L")
    
    ' 2nd possibility: right-curved rail element
    kk = k
    Call ergaenze_bauteil(kk, "bogen rechts")
    Call try(kk, tiefe + 1, weg + "R")

    ' 3rd possibility: straight rail element
    kk = k
    Call ergaenze_bauteil(kk, "gerade")
    Call try(kk, tiefe + 1, weg + "-")
  
  End If
  
try_ende:
End Sub

Sub ergaenze_bauteil(k As kopf_type, bauteil As String)
  ' add a railway element ('bauteil') to the current track;
  ' to be more precise: adjust the geometrical parameters of the current head ('k')
  Dim mx1 As Integer
  Dim nx1 As Integer
  Dim my1 As Integer
  Dim ny1 As Integer
  
  Select Case bauteil
  
    Case "gerade"
      ' Straight element: No change in direction; only change the position
      '
      ' Mathematical background:
      ' Length of a straight element is defined here as 1/2.
      ' With direction alpha and using the formulas decribed above,
      ' the change in x direction = 1/2 * cos(alpha) = 1/2 * (m * squareroot(3)/2 + n * 1/2) and
      ' the change in y direction = 1/2 * sin(alpha) = 1/2 * (p * squareroot(3)/2 + q * 1/2).
      ' When taking into account the decomposition of x into mx and nx and y into my and ny (see above):
      '     x = mx * squareroot(3)/4 + nx * 1/4 and
      '     y = my * squareroot(3)/4 + ny * 1/4
      ' then the new coordinates become
      '     x_new = (mx+m) * squareroot(3)/4 + (nx+n) * 1/4 and
      '     y_new = (my+m) * squareroot(3)/4 + (ny+n) * 1/4.
      ' The assignments below update these 4 parameters (mx, nx, my, ny) accordingly.
      ' (Note: for adding left and right curve elements, similar mathematics is being applied.)
      k.mx = k.mx + k.m
      k.nx = k.nx + k.n
      k.my = k.my + k.p
      k.ny = k.ny + k.q
      
    Case "bogen links"
      ' Left curve element
      ' 1) change the position
      mx1 = k.mx + k.m
      nx1 = k.nx + k.n
      my1 = k.my + k.p
      ny1 = k.ny + k.q
      
      k.mx = mx1 - (2 * k.p - k.q)
      k.nx = nx1 - (2 * k.q - 3 * k.p)
      k.my = my1 + (2 * k.m - k.n)
      k.ny = ny1 + (2 * k.n - 3 * k.m)
      
      ' 2) change the direction
      k.alpha = (k.alpha + 30) Mod 360
      Call adjust_mnpq(k)

    Case "bogen rechts"
      ' Right curve element
      ' 1) change the position
      mx1 = k.mx + k.m
      nx1 = k.nx + k.n
      my1 = k.my + k.p
      ny1 = k.ny + k.q
      
      k.mx = mx1 + (2 * k.p - k.q)
      k.nx = nx1 + (2 * k.q - 3 * k.p)
      k.my = my1 - (2 * k.m - k.n)
      k.ny = ny1 - (2 * k.n - 3 * k.m)
      
      ' 2) change the direction
      k.alpha = (k.alpha + 330) Mod 360 ' Attention: -30 mod 360 yields to something different
      Call adjust_mnpq(k)
      
    Case Else
      Debug.Print "Error: Unbekanntes Bauteil"
  End Select

End Sub

Sub adjust_mnpq(k As kopf_type)
  ' Determine the coefficients m, n, p, q from alpha.
  ' See above (definition of this data structure) for more backgroud.
  
  ' determine the cosine parameters of the direction
  Select Case k.alpha
    Case 0
      k.m = 0
      k.n = 2
    Case 30, 330
      k.m = 1
      k.n = 0
    Case 60, 300
      k.m = 0
      k.n = 1
    Case 90, 270
      k.m = 0
      k.n = 0
    Case 120, 240
      k.m = 0
      k.n = -1
    Case 150, 210
      k.m = -1
      k.n = 0
    Case 180
      k.m = 0
      k.n = -2
    Case Else
      Debug.Print "Error: Außerhalb n*30 (cos)"
  End Select
  
  ' determine the sine parameters of the direction
  Select Case k.alpha
    Case 0, 180
      k.p = 0
      k.q = 0
    Case 30, 150
      k.p = 0
      k.q = 1
    Case 60, 120
      k.p = 1
      k.q = 0
    Case 90
      k.p = 0
      k.q = 2
    Case 210, 330
      k.p = 0
      k.q = -1
    Case 240, 300
      k.p = -1
      k.q = 0
    Case 270
      k.p = 0
      k.q = -2
    Case Else
      Debug.Print "Error: Außerhalb n*30 (sin)"
  End Select
End Sub

Function istVerschiebung(a As String, b As String) As Boolean
  ' interprets both strings a and b as loops and determines whether they describe the same loop
  Dim c As String
  Dim lea As Integer, leb As Integer, i As Integer
  lea = Len(a)
  leb = Len(b)
  If lea <> leb Then
    istVerschiebung = False
  Else
    For i = 0 To lea - 1
      ' Compare a with b whereas b is shifted by i
      c = Mid(b, i + 1) + Left(b, i)
      If a = c Then
        istVerschiebung = True
        Exit Function
      End If
    Next i
    ' no shift found which led to the same string
    istVerschiebung = False
  End If
End Function

Function istLRVertauschung(a As String, b As String) As Boolean
  ' checks whether 'b' can simply be constructed by 'a' by swapping all L's and R's
  Dim p As String, q As String
  Dim lea As Integer, leb As Integer, i As Integer
  lea = Len(a)
  leb = Len(b)
  If lea <> leb Then
    istLRVertauschung = False
  Else
    For i = 1 To lea
      p = Mid(a, i, 1)
      q = Mid(b, i, 1)
      If ((p = "L") And (q <> "R")) Or ((p = "R") And (q <> "L")) Or ((p = "-") And (q <> "-")) Then
        istLRVertauschung = False
        Exit Function
      End If
    Next i
    ' swapping seemed to be possible
    istLRVertauschung = True
  End If
End Function

Function LRVertauschung(a As String) As String
  ' returns a string by swapping all L's and R's
  Dim a2 As String, p As String
  Dim lea As Integer, i As Integer
  lea = Len(a)
  a2 = a
  For i = 1 To lea
    p = Mid(a, i, 1)
    If p = "L" Then
      Mid(a2, i, 1) = "R"
    ElseIf p = "R" Then
      Mid(a2, i, 1) = "L"
    End If
  Next i
  LRVertauschung = a2
End Function

Function istIsomorph(a As String, b As String) As Boolean
  ' checks wether 2 strings (i. e. 2 railway tracks) are isomorph and therefore denote the same railway track.
  '
  ' Note: This relation should be an equivalence relation (in a mathematical sense), i. e. (i) reflexive, (ii) symmetrical and (iii) transitive;
  ' Only then equivalence classes can be constructed
  If a = b Then
    ' strings are identical
    istIsomorph = True
  ElseIf istLRVertauschung(a, b) Then
    ' a equals b by simply swapping all L's and R's
    istIsomorph = True
  ElseIf istVerschiebung(a, b) Then
    ' a is a shifted/rotated version of b
    istIsomorph = True
  Else
    Dim a2 As String
    a2 = LRVertauschung(a)
    If istVerschiebung(a2, b) Then
    ' a is a swapped and shifted/rotated version of b
      istIsomorph = True
    Else
      istIsomorph = False
    End If
  End If
End Function
```

Output (here: for 19 elements being available) would look like this:

```
Nr. Solution            #L  #R  #-
1   LLLLLR-LLLL-LLLRLL- 14  2   3
2   LLLLL-LLRLLL-LLLL-R 14  2   3
3   LLLLRL-LLLL-LLRLLL- 14  2   3
4   LLLL-LLLRLL-LLLL-LR 14  2   3
5   LLLL-LL--LL-LLLL--- 12  0   7
6   LLLL-L-L-LL-LLL-L-- 12  0   7
7   LLLL-L--LLL-LLL--L- 12  0   7
8   LLLL--LL-LL-LL-LL-- 12  0   7
9   LLLL--L-LLL-LL-L-L- 12  0   7
10  LLL-L-LL-LL-L-LLL-- 12  0   7
11  LLL-L-LL-L-LLL-L-L- 12  0   7
```

Comment: Many thanks for your answer. Which elements are supported by your algorithm? And yes, please share the code :).

Comment: Currently, my algorithm supports straight rails and curved rails (either used as left or right curve). In principle, other elements can be added, but of course requires coding.

The program is currently written in (believe it or not) Visual Basic for Applications, running in an excel sheet. Currently I am about to port it to C++, then I will share. Hope you have a little patience to wait until I have completed this.

Comment: Thank you. I would prefer VBA version, since C++ will not work on my Mac.

Answer (score 0):

The basic approach I use is to start with a simple track, possibly the empty one and then just add random elements to random open ends, disallowing illegal combinations, like crossing rails, or trying to make illegal combinations legal by replacing a straight piece with a crossing.

This will probably create very few closed tracks. If you want more of those you can try a variation, where you don't add only at the end, but basically in any place and replace one or multiple pieces with a complete set, like a circle, a crossing and so on.